# How to safe restart jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I tried few ways to safe restart either in CLI using the command "java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/ -webSocket safe-restart" which says - "ERROR: Unexpected exception occurred while performing safe-restart command.
hudson.lifecycle.RestartNotSupportedException: Default Windows lifecycle does not support restart."

Tried http://localhost:8080/safeRestart - Jenkins cannot restart itself as currently configured.

Can anyone solve this issue of mine. I'm using generic jenkins via jenkins.war file

Comment: If you have launched as` java -jar jenkins.war`, no can do. Must be [running as a service](https://wiki.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=3604487#InstallingJenkinsasaWindowsservice-InstallJenkinsasaWindowsservice).

Comment: when I try to install it as service via Manage jenkins > Install as windows service. Its throwing the following error Error
Installing a service
[.jenkins] $ C:\Users\sayed\.jenkins\jenkins.exe install
2020-06-21 17:03:06,823 INFO  - Installing the service with id 'jenkins'
2020-06-21 17:03:06,878 FATAL - WMI Operation failure: AccessDenied
WMI.WmiException: AccessDenied
   at WMI.WmiRoot.BaseHandler.CheckError(ManagementBaseObject result)